# I am fetching contacts detail from mobile and when I try convert into json format app crashes

Tags: java, android, json

"This is the code which convert data into json format"

```
private void jsonformatdata() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<=contactModel.size();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonAdd = new JSONObject();
                jsonAdd.put("strModifiedDate", localTime);
                jsonAdd.put("contactName", contactModel.get(i).getPhonebookName());
                jsonAdd.put("uniqueContactID", contactModel.get(i).getContactId());
                JSONArray phone = new JSONArray();
                if(contactModel.get(i).getHomeNummber() == null)
                {}
                else
                {JSONObject num1 = new JSONObject();
                num1.put("",contactModel.get(i).getHomeNummber());
                phone.put(num1);}
                if(contactModel.get(i).getMobileNummber()==null)
                {}
                else
                {JSONObject num2 = new JSONObject();
                num2.put("",contactModel.get(i).getMobileNummber());
                phone.put(num2);}
                if(contactModel.get(i).getWorkNummber()==null){}
                else{JSONObject num3 = new JSONObject();
                num3.put("",contactModel.get(i).getWorkNummber());
                phone.put(num3);}
                if(contactModel.get(i).getOtherNummber()==null){}
                else{JSONObject num4 = new JSONObject();
                num4.put("",contactModel.get(i).getOtherNummber());
                phone.put(num4);}               
                jsonAdd.put("phone",phone);
                arr.put(i,jsonAdd);
            }
            String datatosend = arr.toString();
            Log.e(datatosend, ""+datatosend);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The Error message, which i get in logcat

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ```
>
> ComponentInfo{com.example.vchat/com.example.vchat.Friends_listing}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: Please any one respond quickly so that i can fix it...thanx in advance

Comment: ArrayIndexOutofBound means you are fetching data from list position which do not exists. instead of <= use < in for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert:

`for(int i=0;i<=contactModel.size();i++)`

to:

`for(int i=0;i<contactModel.size();i++)`

The elements in the arrays are starting from zero up to the size. Probably your `contactModel` is empty.

Also next time please include the full stack trace, if you have one, in the question.

Comment: thanku sir fr ur quick reponse and giving ur valuable time ................after ur suggesation it start working but in json data i m  not getting any value only i get in reponse   [ ] .

Comment: @NikhilSingh You are not getting any json values because your contactModel is empty. You should resolve that issue first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
 for(int i=0;i<=contactModel.size();i++)
```

to

```
 for(int i=0;i<contactModel.size();i++)
```